# Why am I receiving an error when importing modules housed in a package built in a Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, containers, virtualenv

When I run my code in a virtual environment I am getting a different output than if I run the code in a container outside of a virtual environment. Same file structure, same code in AB.py, and same import statements in the **init**.py and AB.py files. See the image for more details. Very basic but I would just like to no why python does not recognize one of my modules when the parent container is located in a virtual environment. Thank you!

```py
    Container A
    >AB.py
    >>Package_A
    >>>>__init__.py,
    >>>>Module_A.py,
    >>>>Module_B.py,
    >>>>Module_C.py
    
    
    Virtual Environment Container A
    >AB.py
    >>Package_A
    >>>>__init__.py,
    >>>>Module_A.py,
    >>>>Module_B.py,
    >>>>Module_B.py
```

```
[See image here] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJGpk.png
```

```py
    ## Package AB.py     
    from Package_A import Mod_A, Mod_B, Mod_C
    Module_A.Func_A()
    Module_B.Func_B()
    Module_C.Func_C()
    
    
    ## __init__.py
    from a import func_a
    from b import func_b
    
    ## Module_A.py
    def Func_A():
        print("how")
    
    
    ## Module_B.py
    def Func_B():
        print("are")
    
    
    ## Module_C.py
    def Func_C():
        print("you")
```

Running AB.py in container Returns

```
how
are
you
```

Running AB.py in VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT Returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

Comment: Refer to modules same as their files names ,  `from Module_A import Func_A`, same with functions refer to their function names.

Comment: Does your virtual environment have a `bin/` subdirectory, and did you `. bin/activate` at the shell prompt? (If that solves your problem, I'll post it as a answer.)

Comment: @scootermefecit Yes the virtual environment has a bin directory. Also, I did active my venv by entering the venv directory and using source ./bin/activate

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken I will do this in the future. This exercise was my attempt to comprehend and lock away the container, package, module terminology. I just discovered python returned different results when I performed this exercise in a venv. I spent 1-2 hours trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I needed to change my import lin in my **init**.py file. I changed it from:

```
    from a import func_a
    from b import func_b
```

To

```
    from .a import func_a
    from .b import func_b
```

This was the case for both venv and non venv. I did not specify the parent folder.